# Is defined variable (without a value) considered undefined in PHP?

Tags: php, variables, runtime-error, undefined-behavior

With the following code (PHP 5.4.4-10, Debian Testing):

```
<?php
$a = 0;
$b;
echo '$a: ' . $a . PHP_EOL;
echo '$b: ' . $b . PHP_EOL;
```

I'll have the following output:

> $ php teste.php  $a: 0 PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: b in
>   /tmp/teste.php on line 5 PHP Stack trace: PHP   1. {main}()
>   /tmp/teste.php:0
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: b in /tmp/teste.php on line 5
>
> Call Stack:
>       0.0002     221952   1. {main}() /tmp/teste.php:0
>
> $b:

$b is defined after $a. Why is it considered undefined?
Is it a bug?

Answer (score 3):

It's not a bug. You have declared a variable but not defined it (i.e. you haven't assigned any value to it).